# Updating lodash version to 4.17.4 break the code

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, lodash

I updated **lodash** to version 4.17.4 and Typescript started throwing this error:

`TypeError: _.uniqBy is not a function Uncaught TypeError: _.split is
not a function`

My code looks like this:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
const uniqueRecordType = _.uniqBy(rArr,'recordtype');
```

Has this function been removed from **lodash**?

Comment: Please show your lodash import statement & code where you attempt to use the two functions.

Comment: If someone is getting those error along with Typescript - you might have to change a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs the following should work:

```
const uniqBy = require('lodash.uniqby');

const uniqueRecordType = uniqBy(rArr,'recordtype');
```

How to install lodash dependencies:

```
npm install --save lodash.uniqby
```

When using ECMAScript 5 and CommonJS modules, you then import it like this:

```
var uniqBy = require('lodash.uniqby');
```

Using ES6 modules, this would be:

```
import uniqBy from 'lodash.uniqBy';
```

Comment: I think this is not best way to resolve his problem, because he is using `lodash`

Comment: Why is this not the best way to resolve his problem? Above examples is with lodash in mind.

Answer (score 0):

**Lodash Version 4.17.4** should **import** as:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
```

This is my test on **stackblitz** with lodash version 4.17.4 https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-54031396?file=index.ts

Current Lodash version is **4.17.11** and it will work with

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

So you can upgrade to **4.17.11** or if you want use version **4.17.4**, you can change *import* to `import _ from 'lodash';`

Hope it will help you :P

Comment: import _ from lodash throws error - Module '"/Users/pritisolanki/rri-core-api/node_modules/@types/lodash/index"' has no default export.ts(1192)

Comment: lodash should be imported as modules and not referenced as everything.

Comment: I've tried on `stackblitz` and it worked if  your version is 4.17.4. You're sure your lodash version is 4.17.4